# read text from file to array problem with indexes

Tags: python

hi i try to read text file to array but i have a mistake when i read a number wite 2 digits.

i want to check how match odd number or even number has in each string.
what i did wrong?

to this file1.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 3 6
4 5 8 6 4 2
15 4 22 5 8 21
```

---

```
i get:
   evenArray: [3, 5, 3]
   oddArray: [3, 1, 2]
```

---

```
with open('file1.txt') as file:
   array = file.readlines()




evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0

evenArray = []
oddArray = []

for x in array:
   for i in range(len(x) - 1):
       if(x[i] != " " and x[i + 1] != " " and x[i + 1] != '\n'):
           strTemp = x[i]
           strTemp += x[i+1]
           temp = int(strTemp)
       elif x[i] != " ":
           temp = int(x[i])

       if temp % 2 == 0:
            evenCounter += 1
        else:
            oddCounter += 1
evenArray.append(evenCounter)
oddArray.append(oddCounter)
evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0
```

Comment: Why don't you use `str.split()` to split numbers in line?

Comment: just use `split` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Each line is an `str`. For example, the first line is `'1 2 3 4 3 6'`. This is not a list of numbers, it has to be split and then converted to `ints`.

```py
def is_even(x):
  if x == 1:
    return False

  for i in range(2, x//2 + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
      return False
  return True


with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

  for line in lines:
    even_nos = []
    odd_nos = []

    numbers = map(int, line.split())
    for number in numbers:
      if is_even(number):
        even_nos.append(number)
      else:
        odd_nos.append(number)

    print(f'{len(even_nos)} even numbers: {even_nos}')
    print(f'{len(odd_nos)} odd numbers: {odd_nos}')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split()` like this:

```py
with open('file1.txt') as file:
   array = file.readlines()




evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0

evenArray = []
oddArray = []

for x in array:
   for i in x.split():
       temp = int(i)
       if temp % 2 == 0:
            evenCounter += 1
       else:
            oddCounter += 1
evenArray.append(evenCounter)
oddArray.append(oddCounter)
evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0

print(evenArray)
print(oddArray)
```